# Maya Python: Run polyReduce through a list?

Tags: python, maya

Newbie here. So the teacher challenged me to fix my rock generation script without using the select code. I am trying to run the Maya Python polyReduce command through a list.

```
import maya.cmds as MC
import random as RN

def rockGen():
    rockNumber = input()
    for i in range(rockNumber):
        rockCreation = MC.polyPlatonicSolid(name="rock", r=5)[0]
        MC.displaySmoothness( polygonObject= 0)
        obj=MC.ls(sl=True)
        MC.polySmooth(rockCreation, divisions = 2)

        face_count = MC.polyEvaluate(rockCreation, v=True) 

        # Loop through the items below with the range of a

        for i in range(20):
            # Select faces
            random_face = RN.randint(0, face_count)    
            random_face2 = RN.randint(0, face_count)   
            if random_face2 < random_face:       
                targetFace = [rockCreation +'.f[' + str(random_face2)+':' + str(random_face)+ ']']
            else:
                targetFace = [rockCreation +'.f[' + str(random_face)+':' + str(random_face2)+ ']']            

            # Reduce faces
            MC.polyReduce(p=50, kb=True, t=False, targetFace)
            MC.polyQuad(rockCreation, a=20)
        #Quad up
        MC.polySmooth(rockCreation, ch=1, ost=0, khe=0, ps=0.1, kmb=1, bnr=1, mth=0, suv=1, peh=0, ksb=1, ro=1, sdt=2, ofc=0, kt=1, ovb=1, dv=1, ofb=3, kb=1, c=1, ocr=0, dpe=1, sl=1)
```

So the last bit with:

```
# Reduce faces
MC.polyReduce(p=50, kb=True, t=False, targetFace)
```

the targetFace is giving me non-keyword arg after keyword arg #. 
Can you please advise me what is the proper way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: From the [official docs](https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2017/CHS/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/polyReduce.html) I cannot understand which argument your `targetFace` parameter should be. Which one is it? Find it and use it to name the parameter. Note: I don't see any iterables (e.g. lists)

Comment: you know that I've already answered this question on your previous problem ?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, shame on you for resorting to SO, you pretty much had it :)

Maya's commands typically work so that you can stick the object you want to operate on as the first parameter, and this is no different. So just stick `targetFace` before everything else:
`MC.polyReduce(targetFace, p=50, kb=True, t=False)`

There's a few other issues.

Once in a while the script generates a rock with non-manifold geometries, which poly reduce complains about then and crashes. It might worth using `cmds.polyInfo(nonManifoldVertices=True)` to see if it's ok to run reduce on it. Or you can try to run the mesh clean up command to try and resolve it.

You should also run a `cmds.bakePartialHistory(prePostDeformers=True)` to bake the object's history since there's no need to keep all of those extra nodes floating around in the scene.

I also noticed that Maya straights up crashes if I do 10 or 20 iterations, so the function may require more error checking.

Comment: But that link is about interfaces, this is about objects. Wrong link?

Comment: here is the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57793145/make-input-and-run-loop-to-create-custom-number-of-objects

Comment: Ah yes! I was the one who gave you +1 too!

Comment: we are not a lot responding o maya subject, i think we are giving each other +1 XD.